# Discord Oauth2 with passport.js TokenError

Tags: javascript, passport.js

I'm having problem with my try to figure discord oauth2 with passport.js. I'm using passport.js and passport-discord, at this point I have no clue what is wrong, can anyone help here?

this is my entire strategy logic

```js
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});
  
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    if (user) done(null, user);
});

const strategy = new Strategy({
    clientID: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.REDIRECT,
    scope: ["identify", "email", "guilds"]
}, async(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    try {
        let user = await User.findOrCreate({userID: profile.id});
        if(user) {
            User.findOneAndUpdate({
                userID: profile.id,
                guilds: profile.guilds,
                rtoken: refreshToken,
                atoken: accessToken
            })
            async(err) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                let newUser = await User.findOne({userID: profile.id})
                done(null, newUser)
            }
        } else {
            let newUser = User.create({
                userID: profile.id,
                username: profile.username,
                discriminator: profile.discriminator,
                rtoken: refreshToken,
                atoken: accessToken,
                userIcon: profile.avatar,
                userEmail: profile.email,
                staff: false,
                guilds: profile.guilds
            })
            const savedUser = await newUser.save();
            done(null, savedUser);
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        done(err, null);
    }
})

passport.use("discord", strategy);

app.get("/login", passport.authenticate('discord'), (req, res) => {})

app.get("/login/callback", passport.authenticate("discord", {failureRedirect: "/"}), async(req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/me")
})
```

checkAuth.js

```js
module.exports.checkAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) { 
        return res.redirect("/login");
    } else {
        return next();
    }
}
```

Can anyone pls help me, I think I did something wrong

Comment: What does the error say?